# Rails decorator spec -> UrlGenerationError and no #current_user_admin? helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rspec-rails, specifications, draper

So I am getting `ActionController::UrlGenerationError` for `link_to` and `undefined method` for current user admin.

I suspect that something is wrong with rspec setup. Also I think there might be a problem with `concat`

Also in views it works flawelessly.

**Relevant decorator code:**

```
class ArticleDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  decorates_association :comments

  def navigation_links_list(without)
    h.concat list_element { h.link_to h.t('jump_top'), anchor: 'top' } unless without == :top
    unless without == :comments_section
      h.concat list_element { h.link_to h.t('jump_to_comment_section'), anchor: 'comments' }
    end
    list_element { h.link_to h.t('jump_to_new_comment'), anchor: 'new_comment' } unless without == :new_comment
  end

  def show_to_admin
    return unless h.admin_signed_in?
    h.concat list_element { h.link_to h.t('edit_article'), h.edit_article_path(object) }
    list_element do
      h.link_to h.t('delete_article'), h.article_path(object),
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: h.t('are_you_sure') }
    end
  end

  [...]

  private

  [...]

  def list_element
    h.content_tag :li, yield
  end
end
```

**Relevant spec code:**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ArticleDecorator, type: :decorator do
  let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
  let(:article) { FactoryGirl.create(:article) }
  subject { article.decorate }

  describe '#show_to_admin' do
    context 'with admin signed out' do
      it 'returns nil' do
        expect(subject.show_to_admin).to eql nil
      end
    end
  end

  describe '#navigation_links_list' do
    context 'without "top" link' do
      it 'returns jump to comments and jump to articles links' do
        expect(subject.navigation_links_list(:top)).to eql 'whatever'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Result of running spec:**

```
Failures:

  1) ArticleDecorator#show_to_admin with admin signed out returns nil
     Failure/Error: return unless h.admin_signed_in?

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `admin_signed_in?' for #<#<Class:0x00000005845da0>:0x00000005235a00>
       Did you mean?  admin_session_url
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/helper_proxy.rb:35:in `block in define_proxy'
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/helper_proxy.rb:16:in `method_missing'
     # ./app/decorators/article_decorator.rb:15:in `show_to_admin'
     # ./spec/decorators/article_decorator_spec.rb:11:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:16:in `cleaning'
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:98:in `cleaning'
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) ArticleDecorator#navigation_links_list without "top" link returns jump to comments and jump to articles links
     Failure/Error: h.concat list_element { h.link_to h.t('jump_to_comment_section'), anchor: 'comments' }

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index"}
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/helper_proxy.rb:35:in `block in define_proxy'
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/helper_proxy.rb:16:in `method_missing'
     # ./app/decorators/article_decorator.rb:9:in `block in navigation_links_list'
     # ./app/decorators/article_decorator.rb:55:in `list_element'
     # ./app/decorators/article_decorator.rb:9:in `navigation_links_list'
     # ./spec/decorators/article_decorator_spec.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:16:in `cleaning'
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:98:in `cleaning'
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # /home/dominikduda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.5.3/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Here is my rails helper:**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!') if Rails.env.production?

require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'devise'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include ActionView::Helpers
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  Draper::ViewContext.test_strategy :fast do
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Any ideas? I can't move forward for 2 days now.

**Requested information:**

From [devise github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)

> Notice that if your Devise model is called Member instead of User, for
>   example, then the helpers available are:

```
before_action :authenticate_member!

member_signed_in?

current_member

member_session
```

---

I solved issue releated to link_to methodd. I replaced:

```
 h.concat list_element { h.link_to h.t('jump_top'), anchor: 'top' } unless without == :top
```

with:

```
h.concat list_element { h.link_to h.t('jump_top'), h.article_path(object, anchor: 'top') } unless without == :top
```

I basically added url generator to anchor (It was working properly in views though). Also I had to do following:

```
before (:each) do
  subject.h.output_buffer = ""
end
```

because I am using `concat` and this method appends current view output buffer which is not available in decorator spec.

EDIT:

Mine and Paweł Duda sollution from comments works, but they produce links which are reloading page.

Comment: Speaking of 1): please include info about your '#admin_signed_in?' method and where it is defined. 2) You are not passing any base URL and this is the reason for error. You can try a `link_to "h.t('jump_top')", "#top"` instead - it should work just fine

Comment: what link does your method produce now?